# Bind indexing of image views and textviews with audio player

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I want to bind indexing of image views and textviews with audio player. So that when audioplayer is paused updating of imageviews and textviews should be paused as well and when audioplayer is resumed then updating of image views and textviews should be resumed as well.

```
- (void)updateText:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
if (index < [myArray count])
{
    self.textView.text = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:index];
    self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];
    index++;
}
else {
    index = 0;
}

   }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImageView* imageView;   //the view that gets updated

int current_selected_image_index = 0;
float time_for_next_image = 0.0;

AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer;

NSArray* image_times;   //an array of float values representing each 
                    //time when the view should update

NSArray* image_names;   //an array of the image file names 

-(void)update_view
 {
UIImage* next_image_to_play = [image_names objectAtIndex:current_selected_image_index];
imageView.image = next_image_to_play;
 }

-(void)bind_view_to_audioplayer
 {
while(audioPlayer.isPlaying)
{
    float currentPlayingTime = (float)audioPlayer.currentTime;
    if(currentPlayingTime >= time_for_next_image)
    {
        current_selected_image_index++;
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(update_view) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        time_for_next_image = [image_times objectAtIndex:[current_selected_image_index+1)];
    }
    [NSThread sleep:0.2];
}
 }

-(void)init_audio
{
current_selected_image_index = 0;
time_for_next_image = [image_times objectAtIndex:1];
} 

-(void)play_audio
{
[audioPlayer play];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(bind_view_to_audioplayer) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)pause_audio
{
[audioPlayer pause];
//that's all, the background thread exits because audioPlayer.isPlaying == NO
//the value of current_selected_image_index stays where it is, so [self play_audio] picks up 
//where it left off.
 }
```

also, add self as observer for the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: notification to reset when the audioplayer finishes playing.

Hope it helps you.